# How to install Linux on an MSI laptop(Gl62M 7REX model) having 128GB SSD as primary storage and 1 tb Hard disk as secondary storage

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I want to install Debian + KDE on my MSI laptop(Gl62M 7REX model) having 128GB SSD as primary storage(windows 10 installed currently) and 1TB Hard disk.
I tried installing by disabling the fast boot on the BIOS, disabled the secure boot on the BIOS but after booting the USB stick, I started getting an error saying that the wireless drivers cannot be found, which is necessary for connecting to wifi and downloading the KDE plasma from the network.

I even tried installing Kubuntu and Ubuntu 18.04LTS, but I started getting errors saying Casper not found, kernel loaded earlier something like that.

I really need to install Linux distro on my laptop and remove Windows as I have some academic needs that require the use of Linux. I don't want to dual boot my system.

Comment: Secure boot and similar problems have most likely nothing to do with the wireless driver problems. The booting problem, you solved it. Now you have another problem, the wireless driver problem. A possible workaround: connect your laptop with a wired ethernet cable into your router, and install/update your system with it.

Comment: What is in your lspci output? The most probable cause is that simply your wireless chip is too young and it is not supported by the kernel of the latest Ubuntu LTS. A kernel upgrade could solve it.

Comment: According [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401479), you might have more success by booting with an acpi=off kernel parameter.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by myself after doing some research. Since the comments didn't help quite well, I decided to write a blog post regarding that.

*Blog Link* (removed, write it down here)

Comment: You shall not post your blog in here! Share direct instructions here!